# How to get the sqlite row id in view pager

Tags: android, sqlite, android-viewpager

I have created a view pager with textview that loads text from SQLITE database. On delete button clicked I want to delete this page but I am not able to get the id for the sqlite row.

```
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            page = position;

        }
```

The above code return the position of the slide i.e. is 0 ,1,2,3, etc. but not the sqlite row id. Is there any way that I can get the id associated for this textview.

Comment: Provide more code, what adapter are You using?

Comment: I don't know about ViewPager, but note that your table's 'integer primary key', accessible as '_id' is a synonym for rowid.